# How much readable text can fit inside an ATTINY85? Feasibility of scrolling a booklet on a 0.91-inch OLED display

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, c++, i2c, attiny85

I'm a total beginner, so I've been talking with Chatgpt regarding the capabilities of the **Attiny85** microcontroller. But the AI would hallucinate a lot and give only partially right answers (because it relies on patterns and knowledge from its training data or something). So I came here to ask for some guidance and insights on the following questions:

1. How much readable text can the Attiny85 accommodate considering variables such as the programs, libraries, and fonts?
2. Is it possible to create a mini text reader using an Attiny85 and a 0.91-inch OLED display, where the text can be scrolled and read like a booklet?

I understand that the Attiny85 has 8kb of flash memory, but I'm unsure about the actual capacity for storing and displaying text, especially considering the potential impact of the compression of the code.

Any advice, experiences, or suggestions on how to optimize the usage of the Attiny85 and the OLED display for this purpose would be greatly appreciated.

Note: Feel free to correct any misconceptions or assumptions I may have made in my questions due to my limited knowledge in this field.

Comment: start with one of the menu programs that you can find on the internet ... add text to it until memory is full ... your first question is not really answerable ... the second one is `yes`

Comment: If you keep it at simple ASCII (not some multibyte format), one character is exactly one byte. How much of the 8kB is available besides your program depends on how you write the program. Nobody can tell you that, since you haven't written it yet. And when you have written it, you can test yourself by just compiling it (the Arduino IDE will tell you the programs size). Though driving an OLED display uses rather much spaces probably. And you probably will run out of pins. Is there a reason why you are trying this with such a small controller (in terms of resources, not physical size)?

Comment: Hmmm, i dont think i can tell you why i am trying to make this device as tiny as possible... Well, here is a hint: I never graduated from high school.

Answer (score 1):

I will take a SWAG, the approach I would use would be to add external memory such as I2C FRAM. It is not expensive and will work just fine with the I2C bus. I use the 32K x 8 devices. You could connect 8 of them. FRAM can be acquired in SPI as well. I have assumed you are using the I2C for the display so no additional pins on the processor will be needed.

Comment: How does the text get onto the FRAM?

Comment: By writing it there, this can be done in passes as FRAM is non volatile. I wrote a specific program to do this.  I use a Mega to program mine as it has a lot of flash that I just transfer to the FRAM. I have also done it with UNOs and Nanos, they work just fine. Initially I used a Nano and many #ifdef statements. Then each time I would select different tables and program them into FLASH. The table addresses were predefined for the FRAM. Once the FRAM was loaded I then worked on my program with more FLASH and RAM available depending on where the messages were.

Answer (score 0):

The AtTiny85 has 8KB of program memory, which you could store strings in. The more data you store, the less room you have for program code and vice-versa.

For only slightly more money you could use an Atmega328P which has 32KB of program memory, giving you somewhat more scope for storing data.

For some kind of text reader you might want to consider an external disk (like, a micro-SD card) which can be easily attached with a modest amount of extra hardware. The hardware might be a couple of voltage-level converters, if you are going to run the processor at 5V rather than 3.3V.

The code to interface to the SD card might be too large to fit into 8KB of memory (I'm not sure about that) but certainly would fit into 32KB.

You also need the code to interface with the OLED — I'm not sure how much program space that would take up.

You might do it with the AtTiny85, with no external disk, but you would probably only get a couple of K of text, once you had your code and your OLED interface. You could compress the text, but then you need code to decompress it, which might outweigh the advantage of compressing it.

For some sort of "booklet" I think the external disk is the most practical solution. This is what one looks like, with its voltage-level converter, hooked up to my Uno:

[image: Micro-SD card]